# How does high voltage increase power without changing current?

Tags: power, current, high-voltage, ohms-law

I am trying to understand the application of high voltage in electric vehicles in order to increase power vs using high current.

I understand the Ohms law equation P = I x V but I'm just wondering how exactly does the power increase if current stays the same and voltage increases. Wouldn't the rate of energy transfer rely mostly upon the current as this is the physical transfer of energy?

Comment: The same way increasing torque without changing the RPM increases power. Or vise versa.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly apply to motors (which have their own characteristics worth studying) you may notice that long haul distribution lines for transferring large amounts of power across thousands of miles uses very high voltage to do it. The copper costs are much, much less or else the lost power in distribution alone would be much higher. A very high waterfall with a much lower flow rate can deliver similar power to a very low drop river with much higher flow rate.

Comment: `I understand the Ohms law equation P = I x V` - that isn't ohm's law; it's the power law for resistors and, if you understand that power law then clearly, power is proportional to both current and voltage so, if you do understand that law, why did you ask your question above?

Comment: @TMax Andy's comment is completely correct technically. || P = I x V can be understtod as Power = (Amount of stuff) x (Force with which stuff is thrown/pumped/dropped ...). More stuff or more force or both = more power.

Comment: Non technical comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134014/discussion-on-question-by-tmax-how-does-high-voltage-increase-power-without-chan).

Answer (score 1):

You can throw 10 stones per second (I) with a very low velocity (V). You don't transfer a lot of energy. Or you throw these ten stones per second with a lot more velocity. The amount of particels per time stays the same, but the overall energy transfered is still larger.

In the case of an electric vehicel you can think of it like that:
The power of the motor is proportional to the magnetic flux the windigs are produdcing. This magnetic flux is proportional to the current, as well as the number of windings! And with double the voltage, you can drive the same current through the double amount of windings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, I found this the easiest way to understand

Comment: I thought of an analogy of throwing a handful of metal pellets at someone, versus packing the same pellets into a shotgun cartridge.

Answer (score 1):

Analogies are not perfect but let's do a thought experiment.

There is an inclined plane. One side is at ground level and let's say the other side is 1m above ground (the voltage). The length is 10m. Now you place a bunch of glass dishes at the grounded end and roll 1 steel ball per second (e.g. the current). Record the damage done.

In the second experiment, raise the plane on the other side to 2m high (i.e., doubling the potential). Run the previous experiment again (with new dishes of course).

Which experiment would result in more damage given that the the number of the balls being rolled remain the same?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you have two identical 10 V batteries, and two identical 10 Ω resistors (or they could be motors, or lamps, OK, call them loads). Each load will draw 1 A, and the battery is delivering 10 W to each load.

Now we connect the two batteries and loads.

In the first way we connect them in parallel. Initially directly in parallel, but then we can rearrange the components into a beefier 2P battery pack, and a bigger, lower value, resistor.

In the second way we connect them in series. Initially directly in series, but then we can rearrange the components into a higher voltage 2S battery pack, and a bigger, higher value, resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPOAO6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The left hand parallel path combines two 1 A currents into a 2 A current at the same voltage. The right hand series path stacks two 10 V voltages into a 20 V voltage. Those resistive loads could be single 5 Ω and 20 Ω resistors, or, like the 2S or 2P battery packs, be physically made up of two 10 Ω resistors in series or parallel. You can still identify that each resistor and battery are still supplying and receiving 10 W apiece.

It should now be possible to believe that power is strictly the product of current and voltage. Comparing a single battery/load on the top line to one of those on the bottom line, you can double power by either doubling the current at the same voltage, or doubling the voltage at the same current.

A useful corollary of this is that the maximum power of the battery pack only depends on the weight of the batteries, not on their configuration. The configuration does affect other things, like the insulation thickness and the cross section of conductors used to connect batteries to motors, which depend on voltage and current respectively.

Hint - this line of reasoning also works extremely well with transformers and other wound components - for most power, do I need many thin turns or few thick turns? Answer, it doesn't matter, for power it's only the weight of copper that matters. Consider two (or N) identical secondaries that you can connect in either series or parallel ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping